# Angular2+ filter firebase data

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I want to filter some data from the `FirebaseListObservable` but I don't know how to perform it. For the normal case [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/RQOk2EYS6TcYX52JTO69?p=preview) is the solution but using the real time database it doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: In that case just use this Search filter. You will get the expected result. But if not then whatever you have tried just post it here

Comment: i fetch my data from the database like this *ngFor="let pos of post | async" it works but i want to make some filter by search bar i added the filter pipe like this *ngFor="let pos of post | async | searchFilter: search.value " but it doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

It is very ineffective to make a query for the whole list and filter it on client side. You need to make a query with parameters, so you will get only needed data in your subscription. Example is below, different query parameters can be inserted to query object. More info about query parameters can be found here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(af: AngularFire) {
    let listWithQuery = af.database.list('/items', {
      query: {
       equalTo: 'something',
       orderByKey: true
     }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: equalTo don't give everything that is included in the search bar , it just give the same exact word of the key value in the database but in my case i wanna to search in all the collection